# Ruby on Rails 4 Project. How to show all posts from all categories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to show in the index of my blog the last 10 posts of all categories.

I have this in my views/categories/index.html.erb file, but its not working:

```
  <% @posts.limit(10).each do |post| %>
    <div class="single_post group">

        <div class="post_details">
            <h2><%= link_to post.title, category_post_path(@category, post) %></h2>
          <%= image_tag post.image(:header), class: "post_image" %>
          <p><%= post.body %></p>
        </div>

    </div>
  <% end %>
```

This is my categories_controller.rb file:

```
  def index
  @category = Category.all

    @posts = @category.posts.order("created_at desc")
  end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why not `@posts = Post.order('created_at desc').limit(10)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@posts = Post.order('created_at desc').limit(10)
```

Comment: Ok thanks arun15thmay, that shows all the posts but when I click on one of them I have an error:

Comment: @user2092653, what error? Please add this information to your question.

Comment: `= link_to post.title, category_post_path(post.category, post)`

Comment: That's what I was going to ask. Now it's all fixed. Can I ask why is the "category_post_path(post.category, post)" the right path for the post? Where can I find more info about making the paths in the views?

Comment: if you're running on rails 4 (you could add a version-related tag to your question) you can see routes in your browser at `http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes`, where the path- and url-helpers are listed as well. To learn more about nested paths see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies within the association in `categories_controller#index`:
There you define a instance variable `@category` containing *all* categories.
When you call `posts` on `@category` this won't work, because you have a `ActiveRelation` element, that does `respond_to` the `posts` method defined by your `has_many` settings.

As @arun15thmay suggested, turn your query to be

```
@posts = Post.order('created_at desc').limit(10)
```

With that query you avoid handling all categories together with the same effect, that the last 10 posts (no matter what category they are from) are getting selected.

Comment: Thanks ernd enson, I appreciate a lot this kind of explanations, that's what I look in answer in order to understand why things work and to not redo the error in the future. I just had to change the path in the view as @arun15thmay said later.